# How to programmatically obtain information about font selection in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I evaluate e.g. `SystemDialogInput["Color"]` and choose a colour, lets say red, the output cell shows `RGBColor[1,0,0]`.

To view the font panel I can evaluate `FrontEndTokenExecute["FontPanel"]`. If I have some text highlighted somewhere I can change the font styling of the highlighted text (or cell) from the system panel that appears from the `FrontEndTokenExecute`. What I am wondering is if there is a way to programmatically return the chosen font settings analogous to how `SystemDialogInput["Color"]` returns the chosen color. For example, evaluate some code that includes choosing font settings within the system font panel, lets say manually choose Arial 12pt bold in the font panel,

[image]

and return e.g.

```
{FontFamily->"Arial",FontSize->12,FontWeight->Bold}
```

Just so we're clear I'm talking about doing this without any highlighted text or cell in the notebook. One of the problems seems to be -- on a Mac at least -- that the font is only selected if you have highlighted something in the notebook. There are some examples like this in the documentation (`ref/CurrentValue`):

```
Style["xxxx", FontFamily :> CurrentValue["ControlsFontFamily"], 
 FontSize :> CurrentValue["ControlsFontSize"]]
```

This suggest that an answer is possible if the appropriate argument to `CurrentValue` exists but "ControlsFontFamily" and "PanelFontFamily" are not the right arguments in this case.

Also is it possible to programmatically list all fonts available on a particular computer?

**Edit**

@kguler has provided an answer to the final sentence and second part of my question -- this could be used to build my own font panel. I have run @Heike's code and got this (screen grab) on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with Mma 8.0.4. Note the shadowing of `PropertyValue` with `ref/PropertyValue`.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the example under `Generalizations & Extentions` on the help page for `"FontChooser"` in the documentation center does what you want. The code for that example is

```
Needs["GUIKit`"]

GUIRunModal[
 Widget["Panel", {
   Widget["FontChooser", {
     "showLogicalFonts" -> False,
     PropertyValue[{"chooser", "selectionModel"}, 
      Name -> "fontSelectionModel"], 
     BindEvent[{"fontSelectionModel", "change"},
      Script[updateFont[]]]
     }, Name -> "chooser"],
   Widget["TextField", {"text" -> ""}, Name -> "myTextField"],
   Script[
    fontExpr = {};
    updateFont[] := Module[{newFont},
      newFont = 
       PropertyValue[{"fontSelectionModel", "selectedFont"}];
      fontExpr = {
        FontFamily -> PropertyValue[{newFont, "family"}],
         FontSize -> PropertyValue[{newFont, "size"}], 
        FontWeight -> 
         If[PropertyValue[{newFont, "bold"}], "Bold", "Plain"], 
        FontSlant -> 
         If[PropertyValue[{newFont, "italic"}], "Italic", "Plain"]
        };
      SetPropertyValue[{"myTextField", "text"}, ToString[fontExpr]];
        ];
      ],
   BindEvent["endModal", Script[ fontExpr]]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Heike. On my Mac the PropertyValue function has red syntax colouring. The code runs without problems but I am wondering why the colouring? I've added an edit above.

Comment: `PropertyValue` in the widget code clashes with `ref/PropertyValue` which is why the thing is in Red. Interestingly `?PropertyValue` gives a description for the widget use but links to the `Graph` use (which has different argument format).

Comment: I decided to accept this answer because it is a complete solution on Macintosh. If I was a windows user I think I would prefer the invisible notebook method.

Answer (score 15):

I found this long time ago in MathGroup (but now I cannot find the exact link there).

```
fontlist = FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]]

fontlist /. Rule[x_, y_] -> Style[x, 20, FontFamily -> y]
```

[image: Mma Fonts]

EDIT: The source is Wolfram's John Fultz.  Here is the MathGroup link: [V7 FrontEndTokens](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Jan/msg00091.html)

EDIT 2: On windows, if you don't have a highlighted selection, the default seems to be whereever the cursor moves after the command `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FontPanel"]]` is executed. By default it is the next cell. Very first keyboard entry you type after the dialog return is styled with the font selection you make in the font dialog. So, if you execute

```
SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], After, Notebook]; 
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FontPanel"]]
```

and start typing your font dialog settings will apply. However, any mouse move before a keyboard entry destroys the font settings.

EDIT 3: Using Silvia's idea about using an invisible notebook, but instead writing to a new cell in the current notebook also works. Steps: Move selection to a new cell that is closed, write something, invoke the font panel, capture the font options of the cell, delete the cell, and return the captured font options:

```
 fontPanelReturn[] := {SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Notebook]; 
   NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell["text", ShowCellBracket -> False, 
                CellOpen -> False, Magnification -> 0]];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, CellContents]; 
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Word]; 
   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FontPanel"]]; 
  fontops = 
   AbsoluteOptions[
         NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], {FontColor, FontFamily, 
        FontProperties, FontSize, FontSlant, FontTracking, 
        FontVariations, FontWeight, Background}];
 NotebookDelete[EvaluationNotebook[]];
 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]; fontops}
```

Using as

```
 fontPanelReturn[]
```

gives, (for example)

```
 {{Background -> None, FontColor -> Automatic, 
   FontFamily -> "Trebuchet MS", 
    FontProperties -> {"FontMonospaced" -> Automatic, 
    "FontSerifed" -> Automatic, "ScreenResolution" -> 72}, 
   FontSize -> 24, FontSlant -> "Italic", FontTracking -> "Plain", 
   FontVariations -> {"CapsType" -> Normal, 
   "CompatibilityType" -> Normal, "Masked" -> False, 
   "Outline" -> False, "RotationAngle" -> 0, "Shadow" -> False, 
   "StrikeThrough" -> False, "Underline" -> False}, 
   FontWeight -> "Bold"}}
```

EDIT 4: You get the same result if you change Silvia's code so that you select the cell before invoking the font panel dialog and then capturing the cell's font options (rather than the notebook's):

```
 inputFontSettings[] := 
    Module[{doc, opt}, 
    doc = CreateDocument[TextCell["text"], WindowSelected -> False, Visible -> False]; 
    SelectionMove[doc, Next, Cell]; 
    FrontEndTokenExecute[doc, "FontPanel"]; 
    opt = AbsoluteOptions[
    NotebookSelection[doc], {FontColor, FontFamily, FontProperties, 
    FontSize, FontSlant, FontTracking, FontVariations, FontWeight, 
    Background}]; NotebookClose[doc]; opt]
```

Comment: Thanks for this and thanks for the Mathgroup link. I'll keep this open for now in case a direct method of getting this information from the font panel is available, but otherwise this will enable me to build something to do what I want.

Comment: Thanks for the V7 FrontEndTokens link, it's awesome!

Comment: As per my comments to @Silvia `fontPanelReturn[]` and `inputFontSettings[]` don't work on Mac (unfortunately).

Comment: The problem seems to be that on Windows the font panel has an "OK" button whereas on the Mac there is none.

Comment: @Silvia, there are quite few things to play with in the list John Fultz posted. Some I tried (like `"NotebookOneNote"` and `"NotebookOneNoteSelection"`) did not work in V8. Hope it won't be long before Wolfram makes full list for V8 available.

Comment: @kguler That is unfortunate... (I haven't yet got time to test them). Right now the main way I glance a few undocumented functions is to learn from the system files.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you can:

setup a invisible nb and put a sample textcell in it;

-> then select the cell;

-> using `FrontEndTokenExecute["FontPanel"]` to format it;

-> extract the font options you need from the cellexpression;

-> paste it to where you want.

---

Here's how to implement this:

```
inputFontSettings[] :=
 Module[
  {doc, opt},
  doc = CreateDocument[TextCell["text"], WindowSelected -> False, Visible -> False];
  SelectionMove[doc, All, Notebook];
  FrontEndTokenExecute[doc, "FontPanel"];
  opt = Options@NotebookRead[doc];
  NotebookClose[doc];
  opt
 ]
```

Note that if use keep the default font size, no `FontSize` item will be returned.

Comment: +1,  I added some code to your post.  Please edit again if needed.  You seem to have some familiarity with the Front End.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry for a hurry answer... and thank you a lot for your code :) I can not refer myself as familiar with the FrontEnd, but I did occasionally encounter the Chinese font problem a few days ago and did have strong interest on the FrontEnd programming.

Comment: Thanks @Silvia. I started to go down the invisible nb path and decided to ask about more straight forward approaches before continuing. Note that your code is not working on my Mac (or is that code from Szabolcs?)

Comment: Sorry @MikeHoneychurch . I didn't get time to give a concrete code in my original answer, and I don't have a Mac at hand so was only able to verify the code on Win. I thought Mathematica is platform independent, so maybe it's not true for some interface related functions? (not sure about it..)

Comment: What seems to happen is that as soon as the font panel opens the evaluation immediately continues so `{}` is returned. @Silvia would you be able to insert a screen grab of this code working on Windows. I will ask tech support about the platform differences. thanks.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I captured the screen here, wish it helps: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1Ikp1BkFD8XeG0ApIGkoJOteOug6lk5M5G811xLwi-7I

Comment: @Mike It's my code, based on her description.  Works on WinXP. So does `FrontEndTokenExecute["FontPanel"]` return right away on Mac, without waiting for you to choose the font?

Comment: @Szabolics. Yes -- I didn't realize that Windows was different. One of the reasons I stopped trying to do it this way was because I couldn't figure it and thought there must be an easier way -- so i made this question here. So it turns out that Mac doesn't seem to work like you would expect for this. On Windows there is an "OK" button. No button on Mac (see screen grab in my question). I've sent an email to tech support about this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

On the question of listing all available fonts...

Hopefully someone will chime in soon with a native Mathematica way to get a list of all available fonts.  While we wait, here is a way using Java:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment"];

fontFamilies[] :=
  JavaBlock @
    java`awt`GraphicsEnvironment`getLocalGraphicsEnvironment[] @ 
      getAvailableFontFamilyNames[]
```

[image: "hello" in many fonts]

The Java list might not match the Mathematica list exactly given the technology differences, but it is a decent start.